# Foreach repetindo valores ao executar sqlquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Ao executar meu `foreach`, ele está repetindo meu primeiro resultado no sql.

Por exemplo:

1. Ao fazer `select * from tbNome` ele retorna `Gabriel, Rafael`
2. Ao executar o `sqlquery`, ele lista `Gabriel, Gabriel`

   ```
   List<TbListaNome> lstViewModel= new List<TbListaNome>();

   var lista = db.TbListaNome.SqlQuery.("Select * from TbNome").ToList<TbListaNome>();
   foreach(var item in lista)
   {
          NomesViewModel viewModel = new NomesViewModel();
          viewModel .nome = item.nome;
         lstViewModel.add(viewModel);
   }
   return View(viewModel)
   ```

   ;

`TbListaNome` é db set

`NomesViewModel` é minha view model

Comment: Você esta selecionando a tabela correta? O seu select esta selecionando a tabela TbNome. Já o seu modelo, esta nomeado como TbListaNome

Comment: Corrigir aqui, mas continua repetindo e o mais estranho que retorna a mesma quantidade do meu select e substitui pelo primeiro registro

Answer (score 0):

amigo, eu fiz um teste aqui utilizando da mesma logica sua, apenas troquei o comando para executar a query por FromSql e funcionou perfeitamente, todos os 26 estado e 1 DF, ao adicionar na lista tbm funciona perfeitamente.

```
            List<UF> list = new List<UF>();
            var uf = _context.UF.FromSql("select * from UF").ToList();

            foreach(var item in uf)
            {
                UF estado = new UF();
                estado._UF = item._UF;
                list.Add(estado);
            }
```

UF é Unidade Federativa;

_UF é o nome do estado na classe UF;

realize essa modificação simples, e vê se o erro continua... se continuar me avise por favor

Answer (score 0):

Valeu pela dica DFernandes, eu solucionei usando SqlDataReader
`while(reader.Read()) 
{ 
 pessoaViewModel p1 = new pessoaViewModel();
 p1.nome = reader["TbNome"].toString(); 
}`